# React - Typescript - How to function as prop to another component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

There are three components Toggle, ToggleMenu, Wrapper

The toggle should be universal, and used for different functions
The Wrapper should only change background color when toggle is on

The question is how to pass the function that responcible for changing color to togglemenu, that it executs when switch toggle

App

```
import React from 'react';
import { Wrapper } from './containers/wrapper';
import { Button } from './components/buttons/button';
import { ToggleMenu } from './components/settings/settings';
 
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
    <Wrapper>
        <Button />
        <ToggleMenu />
    </Wrapper> 
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

ToggleMenu

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Toggle } from "../buttons/toggle";
import { WrapperProps } from "../../containers/wrapper";
import { test } from "./test"

const SettingsContainer = styled.div`
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: white;
`;

const Container = styled.div`
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: lime;
`;

const TogCon = styled.div`
  margin: 0.5em;
`;

export const ToggleMenu = (props: WrapperProps) => {
  return (
    <SettingsContainer>
      <Container>
        <TogCon>
          <Toggle toggleText={"Dark mode"} onChange={props.handleTheme}/>
        </TogCon>
        <TogCon>
          <Toggle toggleText={"Sth"} onChange={() => {console.log("Sth")}}/>
        </TogCon> 
      </Container>
    </SettingsContainer>
  );
};
```

Wrapper

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

export type WrapperProps = {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  color?: string;
  handleTheme?: () => void;
};

const Container = styled.div<WrapperProps>`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: ${props => props.color }
`

export const Wrapper = ({ children }: WrapperProps) => {

  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("black")

  const handleTheme = () => {
    theme === "black" ? setTheme("white"): setTheme("black")
  }

  return(
    <Container 
      color={theme}
      handleTheme={handleTheme}
    > { children } 
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was solved with ***React.cloneElement***

```
export const Wrapper = (props: WrapperProps) => {
    
      const [theme, setTheme] = useState("black")
    
      const handleTheme = () => {
        theme === "black" ? setTheme("white"): setTheme("black")
      }
    
      const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(props.children, child => {
        if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
          return React.cloneElement(child, { handleTheme });
        }
        return child;
      });
    
      return(
        <Container color={theme} > 
          { childrenWithProps }
        </Container>
      );
      }
```